# strcmp not working?

Tags: c, string, strcmp

I have a strcmp function as so:

```
if (strcmp(userInput, "Yes") == 0)
```

For some reason, it will not enter the if statement, even though I am sure the userinput definitely equals Yes. Anyone have any clue whats wrong?

Comment: How do you input `userInput`?

Comment: You probably got your user input from `fgets`, which leaves the newline attached.

Comment: How are you getting the `usrInput`, and what type is that? More info is needed

Comment: You should post some of the code prior to this line.

Comment: `fprintf(stderr, "\"%s\", userInput);` may help you see what it really contains (alternative, print out individual bytes of the string in hexadecimal).

Comment: You can check the exact contents of `userInput` in a memory window in your debugger.

Comment: Too little information to answer, end of story. A flood of guessing what the rest of the code might be shouldn't be necessary. Simply post the full code.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure you're including the proper header, i.e. `<string.h>`.
2. If you're getting `userInput` from e.g. `fgets()`, make sure there's no line termination at the end, it will interfere with a comparison written like that.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid troube with a tailing linebreak you could maybe check just the first 3 chars:

```
if(strncmp(userInput, "Yes", 3) == 0)
```

Comment: What if the input is "YesASDASD"?

Comment: Well that would match too, but depending on the usecase it could be enough.

Comment: It worked for me where strcmp didn't work. I suppose it was due to one string length wasn't well defined.

Answer (score 1):

As is, your code is fine. That is not the problem.

I suspect you're doing this:

```
fgets(userInput, sizeof(userInput), stdin);
if(strcmp(userInput, "Yes") == 0)
```

Which is giving you a newline char:

```
['Y']['e']['s']['\n']
```

You can fix that any number of ways:

```
if(strcmp(userInput, "Yes\n") == 0)
```

Is probably the easiest. Or you could get input via scaf:

```
scanf("%s", userInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can typecast if you need help.

```
//I am assuming usrInput is a char Array

string str(usrInput);
//string class has a constructor that takes a NULL-terminated C-string
if (str == "Yes")
{
   //do what ever you wanted to in the loop
}
```

Comment: This will not succeed in C